# Combining results from two InfluxDB Flux queries in a single Grafana table

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, grafana-loki, grafana-dashboard

I'm using Grafana with InfluxDB and I've encountered a problem when trying to visualize the results of two different Flux queries in a single table.

I have two Flux queries: one fetches the used memory in GB and the other fetches the used memory in percentage. When I try to visualize both queries in a single Grafana table, instead of getting three columns (host, used memory in GB, used memory in percentage), I get results from the second query appended below the results from the first query.

Here are my queries:

Query for used memory in GB:

```
from(bucket: "telegraf")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mem")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "used")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Query for used memory in percentage:

```
from(bucket: "telegraf")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mem")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "used_percent")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

I am already using the Transformation Reduce, to get the desired 2 columns (host and the metric e.g "Used")
[[image: Output]]

I tried using the join function in Flux and also attempted merging the results using Grafana's transform features (Merge and Organize fields), but I wasn't able to get the desired table structure.

Expected Outcome:
I want a Grafana table with three columns: one for host, one showing the used memory in GB, and another showing the used memory in percentage.

Would I possibly need to approach this differently, maybe by adjusting the query or using another method?

Output before transformations:
[image: output2]

Comment: How does your data look before any transformation?

Comment: I added a picture for that at the end. As you can see i have a dropdown to choose between different hosts i assume.

Comment: I should note the significance of employing 'reduce' at this juncture to consolidate the hosts into a single column and exclude the timestamp. The optimal outcome would resemble the format displayed in the first image but with an additional column dedicated to the second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grafana join transformation - join those results by host column/tag.

Comment: That's the challenge I'm facing. I can't proceed as you suggested because I need to eliminate the timestamp from the side and create a dedicated column for hosts. Hence, the necessity for the 'reduce' function. However, when I employ 'reduce', the output from the second query is immediately appended into that column, preventing me from joining them subsequently.

Comment: @LuisFalke don't generate timeseries, just single number per host. Use aggregation period which is longer then current dashboard time range or modify query and remove time groupping somehow